# Error-handling in query ... Try - catch block

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I have this code.

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');

$msg = 'INSERT INTO tablename ';
$msg .= '(customer_id, invoice_status_id, invoice_number, invoice_date, type, total_excl, total_incl, parent_invoice_number) ';
$msg .= 'VALUES ';
$msg .= '('. $customer_id .', '. 6 .', '. $this->_getNewInvoiceNumber() .', '. $invoice_date .', '.'3'.', '. $total_excl .', '. $total_incl .', '. $this->invoice_number() .');';
$db->query($msg);
```

I want to put it in a try - catch block. I want display an error when the query was unsuccessful. How to do it?

Comment: Start from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive implementation would be this:

```
try {
  $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
   (...)
  $db->query($msg);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "error: " . $e->getMessage();
  // maybe close connection also
}
```

Here though you miss the point, the catch clause will be called only if an exception is thrown, which may not happen, for example if a query returns an empty set, no catch clause will be executed. I don't know much about Zend but if insert throws an exception on failure, than it all makes sense, if not you should look at other methods to handle insert failures.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
try {
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');

$msg = 'INSERT INTO tablename ';
$msg .= '(customer_id, invoice_status_id, invoice_number, invoice_date, type, total_excl, total_incl, parent_invoice_number) ';
$msg .= 'VALUES ';
$msg .= '('. $customer_id .', '. 6 .', '. $this->_getNewInvoiceNumber() .', '. $invoice_date .', '.'3'.', '. $total_excl .', '. $total_incl .', '. $this->invoice_number() .');';
$db->query($msg);
}
catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    die('Something wrong: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```